# Why am I getting a syntax error for this prepared statement in mySQL?

Tags: mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

```
set @name = "Bespin"; 
set @query = planet_in_num_movies(@name);
select @query;
PREPARE stmt from @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

PREPARE stmt from @query    Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1